# Replace third special word in String in Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to know how to replace the third (or another number) special word in Sting in Java.

E.g.

```
String text = "I have test phone test tablet test tv test pc"
```

and I add

```
String specialword = "test"
String change = "smart"
int number = 3 (or another number)
```

Expected output: `I have test phone test tablet **smart** tv test pc`

But if i change

```
String change = "cool"
int number = 1
```

Expected output: `I have **cool** phone test tablet test tv test pc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but here is my method.

```
public static String replaceWord(String original, String specialWord,
            String change, int number) {
        
        int index = original.indexOf(specialWord, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < number-1; i++) 
            index = original.indexOf(specialWord, index+1);
        
        
        String one = original.substring(0, index);
        String two = original.substring((index + specialWord.length()), original.length());
        
        return one + change + two;
}
```

The method `indexOf()` searches a string for a word starting from a certain index and returns it's index, which means we can use it more than once by adjusting the index we start at each time to find the word we want to replace.

After finding the index of the word, we split the string to two strings (adjusting starting index of second string to remove word) and then add the string we want to replace between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code(can modify as per you requirement to handle some other scenarios if you have) -

```
    public String getReplacedString(String input, final String word, String change, final int occurance) {
    int pos = input.indexOf(word);
    String finalString = "";
    int count = 1;
    while (count != occurance && pos >= 0) {
        int len = input.length();
        int subLength = pos < len ? pos : len;
        finalString = finalString + input.substring(0, subLength);
        pos = input.indexOf(word, pos + 1);
        input = input.substring(subLength);
        count++;

    }

    finalString = finalString + input.replaceFirst(word, change);

    return finalString;
}
```